How come if one's building has individual metering, then she/he is limited to installing solar panels on the house panel (common space power)?
I found this link talking about installing solar panels on a condo. One commenter says if one's building has individual metering, then she/he is limited to installing solar panels on the house panel (common space power). Could someone explain what does "house Panel" refer to and what does that have to do with "common space power"? Thank you so very much in advance!

In a multi unit condo, typically, there is a power feed to the building, which is then divided up and individually metered to feed the individual units. Common spaces like hallways, which are not in any one unit, are metered separately and then divided equally between the occupants.
Depending on the structure of the building and rules of that particular condo, the roof may be considered a shared resource, just like the corridors. If so, anything that goes on the roof may have to belong to the condo as a whole, for reasons ranging from shared responsibility to shared benefit to shared liability. And in that case it would be wired to the shared box, not to any one unit's box, just like the hall lights, and any power savings from it would be divided up equally among the occupants.
In other words, like many things about condos, it has to be done as a community or not at all.

Thank you all so very much for your detailed explanations!

There are two key different ways that condominium or similar multi-unit buildings can be wired:

Multiple Utility Feeds

Each unit has its own wires going to the utility. Each unit can, at least from a technical and utility standpoint, have its own grid-tied solar.

Single Utility Feed

A single large feeder goes to a building or possibly even a group of buildings. The power is then split to multiple meters for billing purposes, but from a purely technical standpoint there is only one connection to the utility. In this setup, there can only be one grid-tied solar system, which pretty much by definition is then shared by everyone in the building (or group of buildings), so from a billing standpoint it is shared by everyone and therefore goes to the "common space".
The specifics may vary quite a bit by region, by utility, by age and type of building and other factors. But the end result is the same: If each unit does not have a true separate utility connection then it can't have its own solar power.
There is an additional possible legal issue: Who owns the roof? In a single-family home, you own the roof. In a typical apartment building, everyone owns the roof. If everyone owns the roof then there are liability issues with placing an individual resource there (if the installation leads to the roof leaking, who is responsible?) as well as financial issues (if one person owns and benefits from the solar panels, should that person pay rent to everyone else?).
